# Count number of string occurrences

Tags: text-processing, command-line, scripting

I've extracted strings I'm interested in from another file and now have a list like this:

```
StringA
StringB
StringA
StringA
StringB
StringC
StringB
```

How can I extract the number of occurrences each string has using common command-line tools?

I would like to end up with a list like this:

```
StringA 3
StringB 3
StringC 1
```

Comment: That is **NOT** `json`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor let me quote from above "and I've extracted strings I'm interested in" - I didn't say that the shown snippet is JSON!

Comment: So what am I supposed to do with that information. How is it relevant that it was JSON. May be it could be used to create a different answer, that processes the JSON, so yes put it at the end. But at the beginning, I have to parse that, and realise that it is not relevant. It just adds more effort for the reader.

Comment: I was half-tempted to write a pure-Bash solution, but I think that's not what you want, so let's edit away the reference to that particular shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
sort file | uniq -c
```

Looks simple?

Comment: That's it! `my extraction stuff |sort|uniq -c` does the trick! Great, Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With GNU **`datamash`**:

```
datamash -s -g1 count 1 <file
```

The output:

```
StringA 3
StringB 3
StringC 1
```